# what is the difference between a spark-py image created using docker-image-tool.sh and the one in docker hub

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, docker-image

spark publishes spark-py docker image in docker hub

https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/spark-py/tags

however in running on kubernetes documentation they say you need to build it with docker image tool

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html

```
./bin/docker-image-tool.sh -r <repo> -t my-tag -p ./kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/bindings/python/Dockerfile build
```

is there a difference between the one created with the docker image tool (assuming using a clean installation) and the docker image in docker hub?

Answer (score 0):

I had same question and I did some research.

Below is a copy of [kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/bindings/python/Dockerfile](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/resource-managers/kubernetes/docker/src/main/dockerfiles/spark/bindings/python/Dockerfile) as of today (3/20/2023):

```
ARG base_img

FROM $base_img
WORKDIR /

# Reset to root to run installation tasks
USER 0

RUN mkdir ${SPARK_HOME}/python
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt install -y python3 python3-pip && \
    pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools && \
    # Removed the .cache to save space
    rm -rf /root/.cache && rm -rf /var/cache/apt/* && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY python/pyspark ${SPARK_HOME}/python/pyspark
COPY python/lib ${SPARK_HOME}/python/lib

WORKDIR /opt/spark/work-dir
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/entrypoint.sh" ]

# Specify the User that the actual main process will run as
ARG spark_uid=185
USER ${spark_uid}
```

The `base_img` points to [kubernetes/docker/src/main/dockerfiles/spark/Dockerfile](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/resource-managers/kubernetes/docker/src/main/dockerfiles/spark/Dockerfile):

```
ARG java_image_tag=17-jre

FROM eclipse-temurin:${java_image_tag}

ARG spark_uid=185

# Before building the docker image, first build and make a Spark distribution following
# the instructions in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html.
# If this docker file is being used in the context of building your images from a Spark
# distribution, the docker build command should be invoked from the top level directory
# of the Spark distribution. E.g.:
# docker build -t spark:latest -f kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/Dockerfile .

RUN set -ex && \
    apt-get update && \
    ln -s /lib /lib64 && \
    apt install -y bash tini libc6 libpam-modules krb5-user libnss3 procps net-tools && \
    mkdir -p /opt/spark && \
    mkdir -p /opt/spark/examples && \
    mkdir -p /opt/spark/work-dir && \
    touch /opt/spark/RELEASE && \
    rm /bin/sh && \
    ln -sv /bin/bash /bin/sh && \
    echo "auth required pam_wheel.so use_uid" >> /etc/pam.d/su && \
    chgrp root /etc/passwd && chmod ug+rw /etc/passwd && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apt/* && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY jars /opt/spark/jars
COPY bin /opt/spark/bin
COPY sbin /opt/spark/sbin
COPY kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/entrypoint.sh /opt/
COPY kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/decom.sh /opt/
COPY examples /opt/spark/examples
COPY kubernetes/tests /opt/spark/tests
COPY data /opt/spark/data

ENV SPARK_HOME /opt/spark

WORKDIR /opt/spark/work-dir
RUN chmod g+w /opt/spark/work-dir
RUN chmod a+x /opt/decom.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/entrypoint.sh" ]

# Specify the User that the actual main process will run as
USER ${spark_uid}
```

Below is a copy of current [apache/spark-py:latest](https://hub.docker.com/layers/apache/spark-py/latest/images/sha256-5b3cf4d65685c9d8545d82a5f027e1d2156226629d96223c05691cbc056ef366?context=explore) image layers as of today (3/20/2023).

[image]

First thing I notice is that the customized version is using Java 17 while this official docker image is using Java 11.

There may be more differences. Feel free to add more if you found more!

In general, the customized version can give us more freedom, for example, we can also remove `COPY examples /opt/spark/examples` if not need.